# Trying to get just the URLs from output in Java 

Tags: java, parsing, url

I'm new to Java, and have been looking for a solution.. perhaps i'm not searching on the right terminology.

My goal:  I have a Java class that uses webdriver to go to a page, perform a search... and output the results.  The output results have plain text with URLs.  All I care about are the URL's returned.  So basically, I want to take my output like:

> Search result 1
>   `http://www.somesite.com/blahblah` this
>   is a site from the search results.

but all I want is the URL, i want to dump the rest of the output.  I've looked into 'parsing in java' but not finding what i'm looking for.  Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are your URLs guaranteed to start with "http://"?

Comment: Since you say the returned documents are plain (non-HTML) text, you don't really need a HTML parser; a regex solution like @Felix Ng's should do just fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://[^\\s]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern
    .matcher("Search result 1 http://www.somesite.com/blahbl+ah1 this is a site from the search results.\nSearch result 1 http://www.somesite.com/blahblah2 this is a site from the search results.");

for (int begin = 0; matcher.find(begin); begin = matcher.end())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the regex package: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html

There are other ways to parse of course, but going the regexp route is probably the cleanest.

Comment: Or more specifically something like: `http\\://[^ ]+`

Comment: Thanks everyone!  perfect.  that's what I wanted.  I didn't know about RegEx.  But i'm hooked. this is really cool.  I am passing the results as a variable as the.matcher() and then use that pattern you suggested... and bingo... all the URL's.  perfect.  thanks again!

Comment: Don't forget detecting https too. There should be plenty of examples for advanced regexp detecting URLs in text if you just do a quick search here on stackoverflow.com.